# 'Show block on specific pages' wraps url in paragraph tags

Tags: 6, blocks

I have a Drupal 6 site and I want to add a block to a page. This block is generated from a custom module, from the `hook_block` function.

Under the blocks admin section, under `Page specific visibility settings` header, there is the setting for `Show block on specific pages`. I've entered my url under `Pages` and selected `Show on only the listed pages.`

When I click save, Drupal wraps my path in `<p>` tags. I don't have anything in my module that would be overriding the default drupal behavior. Why is this happening and how can I get it to stop?

Answer (score 1):

We have CK Editor enabled on our site. In order to fix this, I had to go under CK Editor and change the profile for my role. Under `Visibility Settings`, there was a place to specify paths of textareas *not* to affect. I put in the path and I'm good to go!